# Error creating bean with name 'endpoint' in spring 4

Tags: spring, web-services, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jax-ws

I created a JAX-WS application with spring (4.2.4), spring boot (1.3.1) and apache cxf (3.1.4). While running the application in apache server 8, i am getting below error:

```
2015-12-24 16:15:35.767  INFO 3956 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'errorPageFilter' to: [/*]
2015-12-24 16:15:36.120  WARN 3956 --- [ost-startStop-1] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'endpoint' defined in com.pd.config.PDConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.xml.ws.Endpoint]: Factory method 'endpoint' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.pd.webService.response.model.ResponseModel com.pd.webService.Impl.ServiceInterfaceImpl.responseModel; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.pd.webService.response.model.ResponseModel] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
2015-12-24 16:15:36.135 ERROR 3956 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'endpoint' defined in com.pd.config.PDConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.xml.ws.Endpoint]: Factory method 'endpoint' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.pd.webService.response.model.ResponseModel com.pd.webService.Impl.ServiceInterfaceImpl.responseModel; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.pd.webService.response.model.ResponseModel] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:764) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:357) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:149) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:129) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:85) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5151) [catalina.jar:8.0.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.0.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409) [catalina.jar:8.0.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399) [catalina.jar:8.0.20]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_60]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.xml.ws.Endpoint]: Factory method 'endpoint' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.pd.webService.response.model.ResponseModel com.pd.webService.Impl.ServiceInterfaceImpl.responseModel; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.pd.webService.response.model.ResponseModel] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
```

Below given the configuration:

```
package com.pd;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

PDConfig:

```
package com.pd.config;

import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

import org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBus;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl;
import org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ErrorPage;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

import org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.EnableWs;

import com.pd.webService.ServiceInterface;
import com.pd.webService.Impl.ServiceInterfaceImpl;


@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class PDConfig extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServlet() {
        CXFServlet cxfServlet = new CXFServlet(); 
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(cxfServlet, "/service/*"); 
    }

    @Bean(name="cxf") 
    public SpringBus springBus() { 
        return new SpringBus(); 
    } 

    @Bean 
    public ServiceInterface myService() { 
        return new ServiceInterfaceImpl(); 
    } 

    @Bean 
    public Endpoint endpoint() { 
        EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(springBus(), myService()); 
        endpoint.publish("/serviceinterface"); 
        return endpoint;
    }

    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer() {
        return new EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer() {
            @Override
            public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
                ErrorPage error401Page = new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, "/401.html");
                ErrorPage error404Page = new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "/404.html");
                ErrorPage error500Page = new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "/500.html");
                container.addErrorPages(error401Page, error404Page, error500Page);
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

PDInitializer:

```
package com.pd.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class PDInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { PDConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }
}
```

cxf-beans.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd               http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws                       http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />

    <jaxws:endpoint id="serviceinterface" implementor="com.pd.webService.Impl.ServiceInterfaceImpl" 
        wsdlLocation="wsdl/serviceinterfaceimpl.wsdl" address="/ServiceInterfaceImplPort">
        <jaxws:features>
            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.feature.LoggingFeature" />
        </jaxws:features>
    </jaxws:endpoint>
</beans>
```

My service implementation:

```
package com.pd.webService.Impl;

import javax.jws.WebService;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.SpringBeanAutowiringSupport;

import com.pd.webService.ServiceInterface;
import com.pd.webService.request.model.UserModel;
import com.pd.webService.response.model.ResponseModel;

@Component
@WebService(endpointInterface="com.pd.webService.ServiceInterface")
public class ServiceInterfaceImpl extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport implements ServiceInterface {

    @Autowired
    ResponseModel responseModel;

    @Override
    public ResponseModel getUserInfo(UserModel userModel) {
        responseModel.setUserName(userModel.getUserName());
        responseModel.setAge(25);
        responseModel.setCompany("MINDTREE");
        responseModel.setExperience("2.8 years");
        return responseModel;
    }
}
```

Response Model:

```
package com.pd.webService.response.model;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ResponseModel {

    private String userName;
    private int age;
    private String company;
    private String experience;
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public String getCompany() {
        return company;
    }
    public void setCompany(String company) {
        this.company = company;
    }
    public String getExperience() {
        return experience;
    }
    public void setExperience(String experience) {
        this.experience = experience;
    }

}
```

Could you please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your `ServiceInterfaceImpl` and the `ResponseModel`

Comment: One of the most useful skills: learn to read stack traces. This is the relevant part that explains where your problem is very clearly: "No qualifying bean of type [com.cncbi.pdp.webService.response.model.ResponseModel] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency."

Answer (score 0):

In the myService bean you have autowired filed of type `ResponseModel`.
You have to declare a bean of that type.

Something like this:

```
@Bean 
public ResponseModel responseModel() { 
    return new ResponseModel(); 
}
```

Looks like when you extend `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport` that bean gets loaded befor the other beans in the spring container. You don't need that - remove `extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport` from `class ServiceInterfaceImpl`

Comment: I have updated the implementation and response class in the question. Please let me know why i cant autowire the response bean.

Comment: @PraveenD See my update. Try to remove `extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport`